# How to re-write email address, developer's name in commit history when convert from Git to SVN?

Tags: git

I use Git 2.10.1.windows.1 (on Windows 10 Pro, x64), then use command

```
git svn http://192.168.23.42/svn/F53140/trunk/Source/corporate_web
```

(A two-years-old SVN repository, use LDAP authentication, My Git server also use LDAP authentication - GitLab Community Edition). After 5 hours of converting process, I very happy, but I don't know how to change developer's email addresss.
I want re-write history from:

```
vydn@e74ca20e-2b41-0e49-8d6f-e074cd2faca0  --> vydn@mycompany.com
thuynt@e74ca20e-2b41-0e49-8d6f-e074cd2faca0  --> thuynt@mycompany.com
etc...
```

How to re-write email address, developer name in commit history when convert from Git to SVN?

Comment: [Have a look at `git-filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#changing-email-addresses-globally-p0tohbf8fO). You can use this function *after* importing from svn to change all the addresses and names. (This will change *all* commit IDs, so do this right after importing, before doing anything else with your repository!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use git-filter-branch (standard/official way) or BFG Repo-Cleaner (faster)

Learn more:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/